# How to check if the user has downloaded the app via SKOverlay?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storekit

in iOS 14, StoreKit offers a new way to promote other apps, `SKOverlay`. the overlay works like a sheet, its visibility can be controlled by a state variable.

```
.appStoreOverlay(isPresented: $appStoreProductOverlay) {
    SKOverlay.AppConfiguration(appIdentifier: "0000000000", position: .bottom)
}
```

It is pretty straightforward to add an overlay however, is there a way to check if the user actually downloaded the app via the SKOverlay? Or is there a way to know the app has been installed after SKOverlay gets displayed?

One way I can think of is to set a timer to call `canOpenURL` periodically the return should turn to be `true` once the app gets installed. I wonder is there a better way to get this information than using a pulling appraoch.

Answer (score 0):

set up a timer inside the view model and pulling the state is the way I went eventually. I am using a `DispatchSourceTimer` and calling `canOpenURL` to check the app installation state after displayed the `SKOverlay`.

Thanks for Adi's reminder in the comment, using `canOpenUrl()` will only work if the promoted app schemes are declared in your application `plist` before submitting it to the store

[image]

Comment: Important to mention that using canOpenUrl() will only work if the promoted app schemes are declared in your application plist before submitting it to the store
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl)